# Get keys from IList<IDictionary<string, object>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have

```
IList<IDictionary<string, object>>
```

How get without duplication keys from all of dictionaries inside this `IList` and put them to `IList<string>` using LINQ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` and `Distinct`

```
List<string> uniquekeys = listOfDictionaries
    .SelectMany(d => d.Keys)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```